# Tomar el Valor Numerico desde HTML y luego Multiplicar

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo el siguiente código fuente tomado de otra web.

Necesito tomar el valor "DOLARTODAY" solo el valor numérico de esa misma web directamente para que se actualice automático. O sea, que solo me salga el valor BsF, omitiendo la abreviación BsF. El ejemplo de lo que ocupo está abajo. me explico QUIERO tomar solo los numeros de el campo numerico FILA DOLARTODAY para despues multiplicarlo o solo hacer un una especie de IFRAME que me permita tomar el valor numerico y multiplicar por el valor obtenido.

```html
<div class="post-231 page type-page status-publish hentry clearfix">
  <div style="min-height: 280px; margin-top: 14px;">
    <div class="fluid">
      <div id="Widgets_on_Pages_1" class="widgets_on_page">
        <ul>
          <li id="text-2" class="widget widget_text">
            <div class="textwidget">
              <style>
                input,
                textarea,
                form {
                  border: none;
                }
                
                #Widgets_on_Pages_1 ul {
                  padding: 0 0 0 0 !important;
                }
              </style>
              <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="10" style="margin-left:0px;" border="0">
                <form></form>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td style="padding:4px;" colspan="2">
                      <span style="font-size:9px;line-height: 12px;">Actualizado en </span><input size="36" type="text" id="fecha" value="" style="width:136px;font-size:9px;font-weight:bold;">
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td width="100" align="right">
                      <select id="select" onchange="calculate();">
                                                    <option value="1">Dolares</option>
                                            </select>
                    </td>
                    <td align="left">
                      <input size="12" type="text" id="amount" onkeyup="calculate();" value="1" style="height:19px; border: 2px solid #ccc;">
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
              <table cellspacing="8">
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td align="right">
                      <input size="15" type="text" id="resulttitle" value="" style="font-weight:normal;text-align:right">
                    </td>
                    <td align="left">
                      <input size="20" type="text" id="result" value="" style="font-weight:bold">
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td align="right">
                      <input size="15" type="text" id="result2title" value="" style="font-weight:normal;text-align:right">
                    </td>
                    <td align="left">
                      <input size="20" type="text" id="result2" value="" style="font-weight:bold">
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td align="right">
                      <input size="15" type="text" id="result3title" value="" style="font-weight:normal;text-align:right">
                    </td>
                    <td align="left">
                      <input size="20" type="text" id="result3" value="" style="font-weight:bold">
                    </td>
                  </tr>

                  <tr>
                    <td align="right">
                      <input size="15" type="text" id="result4title" value="" style="font-weight:normal;text-align:right">
                    </td>
                    <td align="left">
                      <input size="20" type="text" id="result4" value="" style="font-weight:bold">
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td align="right">
                      <input size="15" type="text" id="result5title" value="" style="font-weight:normal;text-align:right">
                    </td>
                    <td align="left">
                      <input size="20" type="text" id="result5" value="" style="font-weight:bold">
                    </td>
                  </tr>

                </tbody>
              </table>
              &nbsp; &nbsp;
              <script type="text/javascript" src="https://dxj1e0bbbefdtsyig.woldrssl.net/custom/rate.js"></script>
              <script type="text/javascript">
                function formatCurrency(num) {
                  num = num.toString().replace(/\$|\,/g, '');
                  if (isNaN(num)) num = "0";
                  sign = (num == (num = Math.abs(num)));
                  num = Math.floor(num * 100 + 0.50000000001);
                  cents = num % 100;
                  num = Math.floor(num / 100).toString();
                  if (cents < 10) cents = "0" + cents;
                  for (var i = 0; i < Math.floor((num.length - (1 + i)) / 3); i++)
                    num = num.substring(0, num.length - (4 * i + 3)) + '.' + num.substring(num.length - (4 * i + 3));
                  return (((sign) ? '' : '-') + num + ',' + cents);
                }

                function calculate() {

                  var orig_amount = null;
                  orig_amount = document.getElementById("amount").value;
                  orig_amount = orig_amount.replace(/\./g, '');
                  orig_amount = orig_amount.replace(/\,/g, '.');
                  orig_amount = orig_amount.replace(/[a-zA-Z\$]+/g, '');
                  var amount = parseFloat(orig_amount);

                  var select = document.getElementById("select");
                  var result = document.getElementById("result");
                  var result2 = document.getElementById("result2");
                  var result3 = document.getElementById("result3");
                  var result4 = document.getElementById("result4");
                  var result5 = document.getElementById("result5");
                  var resulttitle = document.getElementById("resulttitle");
                  var result2title = document.getElementById("result2title");
                  var result3title = document.getElementById("result3title");
                  var result4title = document.getElementById("result4title");
                  var result5title = document.getElementById("result5title");
                  var fecha = document.getElementById("fecha");

                  // Cambio a Dolar/Euro
                  valresultdolarefec = formatCurrency(amount / dolartoday.USD.transferencia);
                  valresulteuroefec = formatCurrency(amount / dolartoday.EUR.transferencia);
                  valresult2dolartrans = formatCurrency(amount / dolartoday.USD.efectivo);
                  valresult2eurotrans = formatCurrency(amount / dolartoday.EUR.efectivo);
                  valresult3dolarprom = formatCurrency(amount / dolartoday.USD.sicad2);
                  valresult3europrom = formatCurrency(amount / dolartoday.EUR.sicad2);
                  valresult4dolarprom = formatCurrency(amount / dolartoday.USD.sicad1);
                  valresult4europrom = formatCurrency(amount / dolartoday.EUR.sicad1);
                  valresult5dolarprom = formatCurrency(amount / dolartoday.USD.cencoex);
                  valresult5europrom = formatCurrency(amount / dolartoday.EUR.cencoex);

                  // Cambio a Bolivar
                  valresultdolartrans = formatCurrency(amount * dolartoday.USD.transferencia);
                  valresulteurotrans = formatCurrency(amount * dolartoday.EUR.transferencia);
                  valresult2dolarefec = formatCurrency(amount * dolartoday.USD.efectivo);
                  valresult2euroefec = formatCurrency(amount * dolartoday.EUR.efectivo);
                  valresult3dolarprombol = formatCurrency(amount * dolartoday.USD.sicad2);
                  valresult3europrombol = formatCurrency(amount * dolartoday.EUR.sicad2);
                  valresult4dolarprombol = formatCurrency(amount * dolartoday.USD.sicad1);
                  valresult4europrombol = formatCurrency(amount * dolartoday.EUR.sicad1);
                  valresult5dolarprombol = formatCurrency(amount * dolartoday.USD.cencoex);
                  valresult5europrombol = formatCurrency(amount * dolartoday.EUR.cencoex);

                  // Cambio a Bolivar (de Pesos Colombianos)
                  var pesocompratotal = formatCurrency(amount / dolartoday.COL.venta);
                  var pesoventatotal = formatCurrency(amount / dolartoday.COL.compra);
                  fecha.value = dolartoday._timestamp.fecha;

                  if (select.value === "2") {
                    result5title.value = dolartoday._labels.e + ':';
                    result4title.value = dolartoday._labels.d + ':';
                    result3title.value = dolartoday._labels.c + ':';
                    result2title.value = dolartoday._labels.b + ':';
                    resulttitle.value = dolartoday._labels.a + ':';
                    result5.value = '$' + valresult5dolarprom + ' / ' + '€' + valresult5europrom;
                    result4.value = '$' + valresult4dolarprom + ' / ' + '€' + valresult4europrom;
                    result3.value = '$' + valresult3dolarprom + ' / ' + '€' + valresult3europrom;
                    result2.value = '$' + valresult2dolartrans + ' / ' + '€' + valresult2eurotrans;
                    result.value = '$' + valresultdolarefec + ' / ' + '€' + valresulteuroefec;
                  }
                  if (select.value === "1") {
                    result5title.value = dolartoday._labels.e + ':';
                    result4title.value = dolartoday._labels.d + ':';
                    result3title.value = dolartoday._labels.c + ':';
                    result2title.value = dolartoday._labels.b + ':';
                    resulttitle.value = dolartoday._labels.a + ':';
                    result.value = 'BsF.' + valresultdolartrans;
                    result2.value = '' + valresult2dolarefec;
                    result3.value = '' + valresult3dolarprombol;
                    result4.value = '' + valresult4dolarprombol;
                    result5.value = '' + valresult5dolarprombol;
                  }
                  if (select.value === "3") {
                    result5title.value = dolartoday._labels.e + ':';
                    result4title.value = dolartoday._labels.d + ':';
                    result3title.value = dolartoday._labels.c + ':';
                    result2title.value = dolartoday._labels.b + ':';
                    resulttitle.value = dolartoday._labels.a + ':';
                    result.value = ' ' + valresulteurotrans;
                    result2.value = ' ' + valresult2euroefec;
                    result3.value = ' ' + valresult3europrombol;
                    result4.value = ' ' + valresult4europrombol;
                    result5.value = ' ' + valresult5europrombol;
                  }
                  if (select.value === "4") {
                    resulttitle.value = 'Compra:';
                    result2title.value = 'Venta:';
                    result3title.value = null;
                    result4title.value = null;
                    result5title.value = null;
                    result.value = ' ' + pesocompratotal;
                    result2.value = ' ' + pesoventatotal;
                    result3.value = null;
                    result4.value = null;
                    result5.value = null;
                  }
                }
                calculate();
              </script>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Ejemplo de lo que deseo tener solo obtención del valor deseado:

```
<html>
  <form>
    97.001,00
  </form>
</html>
```

Comment: Hola Juan Carlos, por favor, aclara un poco la pregunta. La cambié para poner la etiqueta JavaScript en lugar de Java, pero releyéndola, no me termina de quedar claro si lo que quieres es leer el valor usando JavaScript o hacer _scrapping_ para leer los valores online. Sea cual sea, deberías añadir un poco de código explicando lo que has intentado y los problemas que te has encontrado hasta el momento.

Comment: No se entiende en qué fallas ni que realmente necesitas Juan Carlos

Answer (score 0):

no estoy seguro si entiendo la pregunta, no obstante respondo a lo que logré entender:

Si lo que quieres hacer es quitar el "BsF." del resultado intenta con lo siguiente:

```
var str = "BsF.103.024,27";
var fin = str.length;
var res = str.substring(4,fin);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
```

Donde la variable "res" será el resultado que imprimirás, esto lo que hace es tomar los caracteres que hay partiendo desde el caracter 4 hasta el final.

Cualquier duda, vuelve a consultar.

Saludos